# Auth/Login View and Controller missing

Tags: grails, groovy

I typed the following code and i got the login sorted.

```
s2-quickstart com.app User Role UserRole
```

Now, i want to get the View and Controller for the Login Screen. How can i get it. Should i generate it?

It's suppose to be there in `auth/` controller and the action is `login`.

But i don't even have a `auth` model class. All what i have is User model class, which has attributes `Usernmae`, `password` etc.

2.) After successful login how can i redirect the view?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using spring-security-core:2.0-RC2, in this plugin version there is no loginController or logoutController in controllers folder like previous version, all about plugin are in target > work > plugins > spring-security-core-2.0-RC2 > spring-security-core-2.0-RC2

There you can find loginController, logoutController and auht view, i order to overwrite auth view, all you need to do is to create in app views directory a new directory and call it just like the plugin view in this case login and inside login a the views auth.gsp and denied.gsp

I hope this can be helpful

Comment: What about the controllers ? Should i create a folder called login and have authController inside ? What are the other Controllers i should include.

Comment: You do not need to do that, all you need to do is call login controller the default action is index, logic behind index will take you to auth action and by convention it will call auth view.

Answer (score 0):

About your other question **After successful login how can i redirect the view?** , grails spring security core has two behaver.

First you can provide a default target it is done by setting **grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/someurl**

Second and default behaver if someone try to access some url in your app, SSC will intercept the request ask for credentials if user successfully authenticate then user will be taken to that url else SSC will ask again for credentials and so on.

Both behaver can coexist

A simple view example in this [repo](https://github.com/ilmoralito/petstore/tree/master/grails-app/views/login) in github

A simple example how to set defaultTargetUrl in the same [repo](https://github.com/ilmoralito/petstore/blob/master/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy#L146)

i hope it help you